# sendmail is super slow

Tags: linux, email, google, sendmail, godaddy

We are using godaddy shared hosting but have found their sendmail server takes 8-10 minutes to send emails. Besides switching to another host or upgrading to virtual dedicated is there anything we can do to speed it up (something for free or very cheap, that is)?

Could switching our mailserver to google apps affect sendmail?
Could we configure our own version of sendmail & set it up on our GD directory? (ie instead of hitting the server's default sendmail app we hit our "secret" one instead at /path/to/our/webhost/sendmail). 
Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hosting allows it then you can send e-mail by another host using simple TCP sockets - it is simple. You can for example use GMail account for it.

You'll probably not be able to connect to SMTP port (25), but SUBMISSION (587) or SMTPS (465) can be accessible. You need to check it.

Sending e-mail using SMTP isn't hard - this is a simple session:

```
220 something
EHLO you.hostname.com
250-something
250-something
250 something
mail from: 
250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok
rcpt to: 
250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok
data
[here goes mail]
.
250 2.0.0 p1GAcsnd021432 Message accepted for delivery
quit
```

You'll need to add authentication.

Comment: Where can I find more info on your suggestion? I've googled but only came up with this: http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: This link should be sufficient - there are even code samples.